# Wrap outputs of a Wordpress query every second item

Tags: php, wordpress, counter

I think I am pretty close to the solution but I cannot figure out the logic  for where I should close the last div.

I have a wordpress query which requests four posts.

I want to wrap every two items in `<section class="sponsor-row">`

So I have implemented a counter in my query that counts each post, and if it finds two posts have been output it closes the `<section>` div off.

But I cannot work out how I should work out if the row should be closed again.

Can anyone figure this out? How can I make it wrap every two outputs in  `<section class="sponsor-row">` ?

```
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                $the_query->the_post();

                $counter = 0;
                echo '<section class="sponsor-row">'; // Opening the section here

                        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                                $counter++;

                                echo '<div class="grid half">';
                                        echo '<a class="sponsor" href="'.get_the_permalink().'" target="_blank">';
                                        the_post_thumbnail( 'full' );
                                        echo '</a>';  
                                echo '</div>';

                                if ($counter <= 2){
                                        echo '</section>'; // closing the section if two posts
                                        $counter = 0;
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
```

Full query here: http://pastebin.com/e6RzZLR5

Comment: Do you only want to wrap the first two posts on every page in `.sponsor-row` or the first two and the last two?

Comment: Can you tell us what is final output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you do `if ($counter <= 2){` then it will close it each time it is less or equal 2, which means it will close it twice for each item. You should use `if ($counter == 2){` and `$counter = 0;` should be at the top before the query, otherwise you will set it to 0 each loop.

[See comparison in php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)